# ng-repeat filter by one key and two value

Tags: angularjs, json, filter

This is my **JSON** data:

```
[
 {
  "name": "elin",
  "family": "kinoian"
 },
 {
  "name": "simon",
  "family": "santos"
 },
 {
  "name": "sara",
  "family": "pinki"
 },
 {
  "name": "emin",
  "family": "richard"
 }
]
```

As you can see,I have 2 key in each row "**name**" and "**family**. 
This is my ng-repeat filtering by json object "**search**":

```
<li ng-repeat="membr in familyMember| filter:search">
  <span> {{membr.name}} - {{membr.family}}</span>
</li>
```

And these are my inputs for filtering:

```
By name: <input type="text" ng-model="search.name1"> 
and <input type="text" ng-model="search.name2">

By family: <input type="text" ng-model="search.family">
```

I need the rows which **name** is "*elin*" and "*sara*". I`m looking for "**AND Condition**" in filtering. How can I do that?

Comment: tell  a sample input and output

Comment: input: "eiln" and "sara" -- output: show 1st and 3rd row which has "elin" and "sara" in name.

Comment: did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, no, you're not looking for an AND condition, but for an OR. Indeed, a family member can't be named "elin" and "sara" at the same time.

Now, if you read the documentation for the `filter` filter, you'll see that it accepts a function as argument, which must return a truthy value if the value is accepted, and a truthy value if it's rejected. So all you need is

```
ng-repeat="member in familyMember| filter:isAccepted">
```

and

```
$scope.isAccepted = function(member) {
    return member.name === $scope.search.name1 || member.name === $scope.search.name2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom filter with OR condition.

```
 $scope.nameFilter = function(member) {
    var result = (member.name == $scope.membr.name1) ||
      (member.name == $scope.membr.name2) ||
      (member.family == $scope.membr.family);
    return result;
  };
```

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.familyMember = [{
    "name": "elin",
    "family": "kinoian"
  }, {
    "name": "simon",
    "family": "santos"
  }, {
    "name": "sara",
    "family": "pinki"
  }, {
    "name": "emin",
    "family": "richard"
  }];
  $scope.nameFilter = function(member) {
    var result = (member.name == $scope.membr.name1) ||
      (member.name == $scope.membr.name2) ||
      (member.family == $scope.membr.family);
    return result;
  };

}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    By name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="membr.name1" > and
    <input type="text" ng-model="membr.name2"> By family:
    <input type="text" ng-model="membr.family">
    <li ng-repeat="membr in familyMember| filter:nameFilter">
      <span> {{membr.name}} - {{membr.family}}</span>
    </li>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: mark as answer if it has helped, click the tick mark next to the answer

Answer (score 0):

**Try this working demo :**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {   
  $scope.familyMember = [
 {
  "name": "elin",
  "family": "kinoian"
 },
 {
  "name": "simon",
  "family": "santos"
 },
 {
  "name": "sara",
  "family": "pinki"
 },
 {
  "name": "emin",
  "family": "richard"
 }
];

$scope.search = function(membr) {
  return membr.name === $scope.search.name1 || membr.name === $scope.search.name2;
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
name1: <input type="text" ng-model="search.name1"> 
name2: <input type="text" ng-model="search.name2"><br><br>
    <li ng-repeat="membr in familyMember | filter:search">
        <span> {{membr.name}} - {{membr.family}}</span>
    </li>
</div>
```